# Calculating omega for factor analysis: NA result

Tags: r, reliability, psych, factor-analysis

I am trying to compute omega estimates after exploratory factor analysis to estimate the reliability of the components I've found. Using the `omega()` function from the `psych` package I get this output:

[Output for omega function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBbpO.png)

```
       Alpha:                 0.8 
        G.6:                   0.86 
        Omega Hierarchical:    0.37 
        Omega H asymptotic:    0.43 
        Omega Total            0.86 

    Schmid Leiman Factor loadings greater than 

 0.2 
              g   F1*   F2*   F3*   h2   u2   p2
    EMS1   0.30        0.71       0.59 0.41 0.15
    EMS3        -0.21  0.64       0.53 0.47 0.05
    EMS4         0.62             0.41 0.59 0.04
    EMS7   0.34        0.62       0.50 0.50 0.23
    EMS8   0.36        0.42       0.32 0.68 0.40
    EMS9         0.57             0.33 0.67 0.00
    EMS10              0.39       0.20 0.80 0.11
    EMS11        0.72             0.51 0.49 0.02
    EMS12        0.68             0.46 0.54 0.02
    EMS15        0.54 -0.24       0.41 0.59 0.02
    EMS16  0.22        0.77       0.63 0.37 0.08
    EMS19        0.65             0.52 0.48 0.01
    EMS20  0.27        0.53       0.36 0.64 0.21
    EMS21        0.62             0.40 0.60 0.04
    EMS23        0.63             0.42 0.58 0.07
    EMS24  0.68                   0.45 0.55 1.02
    EMS25  0.73                   0.56 0.44 0.95
    EMS27  0.45        0.20       0.25 0.75 0.83
    EMS28  0.78                   0.59 0.41 1.02
    EMS34  0.26  0.31  0.48       0.34 0.66 0.20

    With eigenvalues of:
      g F1* F2* F3* 
    2.5 3.4 2.9 0.0 

    general/max  0.73   max/min =   Inf
    mean percent general =  0.27    with sd =  0.36 and cv of  1.33 
    Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  0.28 

    The degrees of freedom are 133  and the fit is  0.8 
    The number of observations was  601  with Chi Square =  471.81  with prob <  1.9e-39
    The root mean square of the residuals is  0.04 
    The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.05
    RMSEA index =  0.066  and the 10 % confidence intervals are  0.059 0.072
    BIC =  -379.21

    Compare this with the adequacy of just a general factor and no group factors
    The degrees of freedom for just the general factor are 170  and the fit is  5.4 
    The number of observations was  601  with Chi Square =  3195.63  with prob <  0
    The root mean square of the residuals is  0.22 
    The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.24 

    RMSEA index =  0.173  and the 10 % confidence intervals are  0.167 0.177
    BIC =  2107.87

    Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                    g  F1*  F2* F3*
    Correlation of scores with factors            0.9 0.94 0.93   0
    Multiple R square of scores with factors      0.8 0.89 0.86   0
    Minimum correlation of factor score estimates 0.6 0.78 0.73  -1

     Total, General and Subset omega for each subset
                                                     g  F1*  F2* F3*
    Omega total for total scores and subscales    0.86 0.82 0.85  NA
    Omega general for total scores and subscales  0.37 0.08 0.34  NA
    Omega group for total scores and subscales    0.58 0.75 0.51  NA
    Warning messages:
    1: In fac(r = r, nfactors = nfactors, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate,  :
       A loading greater than abs(1) was detected.  Examine the loadings carefully.
    2: In fac(r = r, nfactors = nfactors, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate,  :
      An ultra-Heywood case was detected.  Examine the results carefully
    3: In cov2cor(t(w) %*% r %*% w) :
      diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
```

This is how I am calling the function:
`omega(df[,items],nfactors=3)`

After searching for guidance, I could not find why omega was not computed for the 3rd factor. I am not sure if it an issue related to one of the warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fac(r = r, nfactors = nfactors, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate,  :
   A loading greater than abs(1) was detected.  Examine the loadings carefully.
2: In fac(r = r, nfactors = nfactors, n.obs = n.obs, rotate = rotate,  :
  An ultra-Heywood case was detected.  Examine the results carefully
3: In cov2cor(t(w) %*% r %*% w) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because Omega is calculated by fitting a CFA model, and in your case with 3 factors, factor number 3 is used for identification reasons. So you wouldn't expect Omega to be calculated for it